# How can I remove non working days from a date calculation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to remove Public holidays and working days from two date calculations  In a query I'm running.  Problem is that I'm still fairly new to SQL and having difficulty in the final part.

I've created a function for the Working Days and Public Holidays that seem to run fine.  I just don't know who to subtract them from the DateDiff Calculations.

Below are two bits of code written. The first is for the function, the second is for the DateDiff Calculations.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].fn_CountWeekDays --To Create The Function
(
@fromdate Datetime,
@todate Datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(SELECT
(DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
 -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
 -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicHolidays AS h WHERE h.PublicHolidayDate 
  BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate)
  As NoOfWeekDays
  )

SELECT a.* --the DateDiff
    ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,b.Last_Action_Date,a.Last_Action_Date),0) 
'Date1'
    ,datediff(day, Min(a.Last_Action_Date) over (partition by a. 
[App_ID]), 
a.Last_Action_Date) 'Date2'
FROM (select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [App_ID] ORDER BY 
Last_Action_Date)RowRank
  from    [dbo].[Audit_Log]
  )a
LEFT JOIN (select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [App_ID] ORDER BY 
Last_Action_Date)RowRank
  from    [dbo].[Audit_Log]
  )b
ON a.[App_ID] = b.[App_ID]
AND a.RowRank = b.RowRank +1  
ORDER BY a.App_ID ASC, a.last_Action_Date ASC
```

The Non Working days need to be subtracted from 'Date1 and also 'Date2'

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio (If that's what you mean)

Comment: what you need a date dimension table, here's [one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's definitely something I'll have a look at however, due to time constraints I was wondering if there was a quicker solution.

Comment: @WesleyO a date dimension table is an extremely quick solution

Comment: You need "to remove ... **working days**"? For a function that counts "weekdays" (according to the name of the function)?

Comment: @Mahzar Thanks it was quick.  But I'm still stuck on how to exclude them from the second query.  Like I said I'm fairly new to SQL

Comment: Use a calendar table. For US, you can use [Aaron Bertrand's script to create and populate it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)